Laser Scan Fails When Robot Starts Running
I'm running the ROS navigation stack. Everything works well, the robot localises, the paths are generated and cmd_vel works, except for one key issue. Once a goal is set, the path is made and the robot starts moving, the Laser Scan starts giving an error. The robot goes completely blind after that. Its localisation fails and obstacle avoidance also fails.
I'll attach below my Launch File and images depicting the error that is being given.
Launch File
<launch>

  <!-- Transformation Configuration ... Setting Up the Relationships Between Coordinate Frames --> 
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" args="0.25 0 0.2 -1.57 0 0 base_link laser 30" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_footprint base_link 30" />
  <!-- odom to base_footprint transform will be provided by the robot_pose_ekf node -->
  <!-- map to odom will be provided by the AMCL -->
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_to_odom" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map odom 30" />

  <!-- Lidar Data Publisher Using RPLIDAR from Slamtec -->
  <!-- Used for obstacle avoidance and can be used for mapping --> 
  <!-- Publish: /scan -->
  <node name="rplidarNode"          pkg="rplidar_ros"  type="rplidarNode" output="screen">
    <param name="serial_port"         type="string" value="/dev/ttyUSB0"/>
    <param name="serial_baudrate"     type="int"    value="115200"/><!--A1/A2 -->
    <param name="frame_id"            type="string" value="laser"/>
    <param name="inverted"            type="bool"   value="false"/>
    <param name="angle_compensate"    type="bool"   value="true"/>
  </node>  

    <!-- Wheel Odometry Publisher -->
  <!-- Subscribe: /right_ticks, /left_ticks, /initial_2d -->
  <!-- Publish: /odom_data_euler, /odom_data_quat -->
  <node pkg="localization_data_pub_2" type="ekf_odom_pub_2" name="ekf_odom_pub">
  </node>

    <!-- Extended Kalman Filter from robot_pose_ekf Node-->
  <!-- Subscribe: /odom, /imu_data, /vo -->
  <!-- Publish: /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined -->
  <remap from="odom" to="odom_data_quat" />
  <!--remap from="imu_data" to="imu/data" /-->
  <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
    <param name="output_frame" value="odom"/>
    <param name="base_footprint_frame" value="base_footprint"/>
    <param name="freq" value="30.0"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>
    <param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
    <param name="imu_used" value="false"/>
    <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
    <param name="gps_used" value="false"/>
    <param name="debug" value="false"/>
    <param name="self_diagnose" value="false"/>
  </node>

    <!-- Wheel Encoder Tick Publisher and Base Controller Using Arduino -->  
  <!-- motor_controller_diff_drive_2.ino is the Arduino sketch -->
  <!-- Subscribe: /cmd_vel -->
  <!-- Publish: /right_ticks, /left_ticks -->
  <node pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py" name="serial_node">
    <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyACM0"/>
    <param name="baud" value="57600"/>
  </node>

<!-- Initial Pose and Goal Publisher -->
<!-- Publish: /initialpose, /move_base_simple/goal -->
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz">
</node>

<!-- Subscribe: /initialpose, /move_base_simple/goal -->
<!-- Publish: /initial_2d, /goal_2d -->
<node pkg="localization_data_pub_2" type="rviz_click_to_2d_2" name="rviz_click_to_2d">
</node>   

  <!-- Map File -->
  <arg name="map_file" default="$(find virtual_simulation)/src/test1004.yaml"/>
    
  <!-- Map Server -->
  <!-- Publish: /map, /map_metadata -->
  <node pkg="map_server" name="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />

    <!-- Move Base Node -->
  <!-- Subscribe: /move_base_simple/goal -->
  <!-- Publish: /cmd_vel -->
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find navstack_pub_2)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find navstack_pub_2)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find navstack_pub_2)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find navstack_pub_2)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find navstack_pub_2)/param/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>

    <!-- Add AMCL example for differential drive robots for Localization -->
  <!-- Subscribe: /scan, /tf, /initialpose, /map -->
  <!-- Publish: /amcl_pose, /particlecloud, /tf -->
  <include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_diff.launch"/>

</launch>

<!--Notes             BUILD CHANGES
1) 28/2: Static tf node is setup above from map to odom. But amcl is also publishing for that. So commenting it out for now. Uncomment if issues arise.
2) Changed the values of the other 2 static transforms to fit our robot.
3) Added the _2 when adding the odometry publisher node
4) Changed the imu_used parameter to false.
5) Added the _2 in the rviz_click node as well.
6) Added the 2 map nodes. Map server is fine, but Map File Node needs to be changed with the actual position of our map.
7) 29/2: Added the common costmaps file as it is. But tuning of the obstacle and raytrace might be necessary.
8) Inflation radius is another tunable parameter
9) Added the local cost map as well. Check on the 'height' and 'width' parameters in it. I feel like this is a huge area I didn't look into properly.
10) Added the move base node and added _2 as well.
11) 1/4: Changed baud value to 57600
12) 4/4: Commented out the 'remap from imu/data' line.
-->

<!--29/2: Because the stack is running, I believe tuning the parameters is what's necessary to make the robot properly navigate.-->

<!--                    RUNNING CHANGES
1) Changed the map file to what I have.
2) Changed to new perfect map that we have.
-->

<!--                      ISSUES
1) tf tree not complete. Map and odom both are not there. [4/4]
  Fix: a) Even on the original launch file, map to odom is given static. Uncommenting what's noted in BUILD CHANGES (1) above.
2) tf tree not joined. No transform from odom to base footprint.
  Fix: Made a key change in the ekf_odom_pub file. Now its working.
3) Lidar is at an angle of 90 degrees clockwise to the visualised front of the robot.
  Fix: Changed the static tf to make it tally. Now its fine.
4) Robot is going backwards instead of forward.[9/4]
  Fix: Parameter Changes 8 fixed this.
5) Map is sketchy and has too many fake obstacles. [10/4]
  Fix: Make a new map. Done!
6) tf error of Laser Scan while running.
  Fix:
-->

<!--                  PARAMETER CHANGES
1) Increased Obstacle Range in common_cost_maps to 3 from 0.5.
2) Did the same for Ray Trace Range.
3) Reduced Inflation Radius to 0.1 from 0.2.
4) Added a line called 1st Map Only on the static map layer. Set it to true. Its default is false.
5) Added Obstacle and Raytrace Range inside the Obstacle Layer. It was initially outside. Note that we are still in the common_cost_map.
6) Added static_map: true in the global costmap file.
7) Changed the width and height to 5 in local cost maps. This was increased from 1.
8) Changed the base_local_planner linear motion parameters signs. Also added escape_vel and set it as 0.11. [9/4]
-->
Launch File.xml
Displaying Launch File.xml.

Error

Terminal output:
[ WARN] [1712833215.157914785]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0362 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833215.390970159]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0359 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833216.291971939]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0369 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833217.565891191]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0441 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833217.599024321]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0440 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833218.362987078]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0412 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833218.388469351]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0334 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833218.602581631]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0475 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833218.698393444]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0433 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833219.322519073]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0341 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833219.602746104]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0477 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833219.617499514]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0406 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833219.650030383]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0398 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833219.761166143]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0394 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833219.877397912]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0338 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833219.981755684]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0382 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833220.156162554]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0460 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833220.174854033]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0365 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833220.214769148]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0597 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833220.216921980]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0401 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833220.420080107]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.1220 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833220.435975249]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.2258 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833220.441154304]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0974 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833220.548961334]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0796 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833220.622750014]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0483 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833220.654747166]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0469 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833220.705920664]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.1236 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833220.802443578]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0613 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833220.826296413]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0518 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833220.876623052]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.1707 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833220.908536524]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0702 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833221.099199500]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0559 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833221.349990487]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0734 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833280.960831789]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0491 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833280.996652916]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.1133 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833281.021455834]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0768 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833281.061278424]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0399 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833332.298455443]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0437 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833337.257216653]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0358 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833337.936701111]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0399 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833337.949382324]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0613 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833338.327354027]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0382 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833373.694022006]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0345 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833374.164290422]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0344 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833380.365677148]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0357 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833384.199906947]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0367 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833387.088629697]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0583 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833387.099479189]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0362 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833387.791067254]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0363 seconds
[ WARN] [1712833396.995733613]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 30.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.0410 seconds

Can someone please help me rectify this?

I think an output of your terminal would help us to help you. My first thought is that there is something wrong with the odometry. You're sure that there is correct odom topic?

It is better to include the code and images in your question, in case of inevitable link-rot
